# Сравниваются элементы в массиве.Если есть,то выводиться длинна элемента или -1. как вывести значение через return ?не используя var к find?

Tags: javascript

```
    arr = ["test", 2, 1.5, false];

function find(arr,value) {

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === value) {
                alert(i);
            }
         alert(-1);   
        } 
    }

find(arr, "test"); // 0
find(arr, 2); // 1
find(arr, 1.5); // 2
find(arr, 0); // -1
```

Comment: что такое "длинна элемента"?

Comment: длинна массива*  arr(0,1,2)  arr.length=3 (ищет в массиве arr значение value и возвращает его номер, если найдено, или -1, если не найдено.)

Comment: `function find(arr, value) {return arr.findIndex(el => value === el);}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
arr = ["test", 2, 1.5, false];

function find(arr, value) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === value) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

console.log(find(arr, "test")); // 0
console.log(find(arr, 2)); // 1
console.log(find(arr, 1.5)); // 2
console.log(find(arr, 0)); // -1
```